# Button clicked on scroll, just one click every few seconds

Tags: jquery, scroll, click

I'm working with a plugin for a Prestashop website that makes a call to the Instagram API every time you click on a button. I needed that to happen on scroll, so:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200 ) {
        $("#pwip__loadmore").click();
      }
 });
```

This works well, however, it clicks the button way too many times and that causes bugs like images being repeated. How can I set a rest or time-out period after each click? Like click, wait 2 seconds before the next click can happen?

Comment: how about `setTimeout`?

Comment: I've tried in a few ways to no avail, how would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
var clickable = true;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200 ) {
        if(clickable){
            $("#pwip__loadmore").click();
            clickable = false;
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            clickable = true;
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is because onscroll event will call multiple times in the short span of time. You could use something like `debouncing`

> The debounce function will not allow a callback to be used more than once per given time frame.  This is especially important when assigning a callback function to frequently-firing events.

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

You'll pass the debounce function the function to execute and the fire rate limit in milliseconds.  Below is the modified code to suit your requirement:

```
var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200 ) {
    $("#pwip__loadmore").click();
  }
}, 1000);

window.addEventListener('scroll', myEfficientFn);
```

## Reference

[DavidWalsh](https://davidwalsh.name/essential-javascript-functions)